# ¿En que momento se calculan las propiedades? C#

Tags: c#, clase

estoy usando C# y me surgió la siguiente duda,

En una clase en la cual defino una propiedad calculada de solo lectura, por ejemplo, una clase sencilla

```
public class UnaClase
{
    public int Num1 { get; set; }
    public int Num2 { get; set; }
    public int Suma
    {
        get
        {
        return Num1 + Num2;
        }
    }

    public UnaClase(int num1,int num2)
    {
        Num1 = num1; Num2 = num2;
    }
}
```

¿En que momento del ciclo de vida de una instancia de `UnaClase` se va a realizar el cálculo `Num1+Num2`?

¿Al crear la instancia o cada vez que hago uso de la propiedad?

Comment: Solo cuando requieras suma. hay algo mas que me estoy perdiendo? una propiedad no es nada mas raro que un metodo, llamado propiedad para facilitar su acceso...

Comment: Tu lo dijiste, cada vez que hagas uso de la propiedad, para comprobarlo puedes usar un Console.WriteLine antes del cálculo.

Comment: @gbianchi gracias por contestar, no tenía la certeza, imaginé que se iba a comportar como un método, pero no sabía si tenía alguna característica que diera alguna ventaja respecto al tiempo de acceso (como si cacheara el valor o algo así) vs una función, por ese lado iba la pregunta :p

Comment: no no.. lo tipifica de otra manera C# para aprovechar agarrarlo por reflection.. fijate en el codigo generado, que es lo mismo...

Comment: De hecho el compilador genera dos métodos, uno llamado int getSuma() y otro llamado void setSuma(int).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El calculo aplicara cuando accedas a la propiedad, ya que al accederla pasara por su ejecucion

Esto lo puedes validar si pones un breakpoint en el codigo, al ejecutar se detendra cada vez que accedas

Igual puedes validarlo con un simple ejemplo

```
UnaClase c1 = new UnaClase(10, 2);
txtResult.Text = c1.Suma.ToString();

c1.Num1 = 20;
txtResult.Text = c1.Suma.ToString();
```

veras como al cambiar la propiedad la suma tambien se ve afectada

Answer (score 0):

Las propiedades también se las puede definir como "puntos de acceso" público a datos privados, ya sea para obtener su valor `get`, o para asignarles valor `set`. Es correcto cuanto ya te dijeron, se evalúan al momento de utilizarlas, otra vez, ya sea que estés asignando valor o recuperándolo.